# parse.framework is not linked, installed via cocoapods

Tags: ios, iphone, parse-platform, cocoapods

I was using parse 1.6.5 and it was working fine in my project. when i udated via pods on 1.7.2 then i got a problem about PFNullability i fixed it by placing NSNullability next to * sign like `NSError *PF_NULLABLE_S error`and it is fixed but after that i got problem with linking. errors are following

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_PFACL", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in SignUpViewController.o
      objc-class-ref in CustomLoginViewController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_PFAnalytics", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o
      objc-class-ref in AllAnalytics.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_PFCloud", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in AdminsViewController.o
      objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o
      objc-class-ref in ScheduleViewController.o
      objc-class-ref in HelpViewController.o
      objc-class-ref in AddAdminViewController.o
      objc-class-ref in TeamReleventViewController.o
      objc-class-ref in PhotosAndVideosViewController.o
      ...
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_PFDateFormatter", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in ParseFacebookUtils(PFFacebookAuthenticationProvider.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_PFFile", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in TeamReleventViewController.o
      objc-class-ref in SearchTeamViewController.o
      objc-class-ref in UserProfileSettingsViewController.o
      objc-class-ref in PhotoSharingViewController.o
      objc-class-ref in CreateNewTeamViewController.o
      objc-class-ref in AddItemViewController.o
      objc-class-ref in AddNewsViewController.o
      ...
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_PFInstallation", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o
      objc-class-ref in CustomLoginViewController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_PFInternalUtils", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in ParseFacebookUtils(PFFacebookUtils.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_PFObject", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in News1ViewController.o
      objc-class-ref in PhotosAndVideosViewController.o
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_Post in Post.o
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_Event in Event.o
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_TeamMember in TeamMember.o
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_TeamAdmin in TeamAdmin.o
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_Team in Team.o
      ...
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_PFPush", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_PFQuery", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o
      objc-class-ref in MoreViewController.o
      objc-class-ref in MenuViewController.o
      objc-class-ref in StoreViewController.o
      objc-class-ref in NewsFeedViewController.o
      objc-class-ref in CustomLoginViewController.o
      objc-class-ref in NVGalleryViewController.o
      ...
     (maybe you meant: _OBJC_CLASS_$_PFQueryTableViewController)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_PFReceptionist", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in ParseFacebookUtils(PFFacebookAuthenticationProvider.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_PFUser", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in AdminsViewController.o
      objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o
      objc-class-ref in ScheduleViewController.o
      objc-class-ref in AddAdminViewController.o
      objc-class-ref in TeamReleventViewController.o
      objc-class-ref in PhotosAndVideosViewController.o
      objc-class-ref in TeamSettingsViewController.o
      ...
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_Parse", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o
      objc-class-ref in ParseUI(PFQueryTableViewController.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_ParseCrashReporting", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o
  "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_PFObject", referenced from:
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_Post in Post.o
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_Event in Event.o
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_TeamMember in TeamMember.o
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_TeamAdmin in TeamAdmin.o
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_Team in Team.o
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_Media in Media.o
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_Link in Link.o
      ...
  "_PFParseErrorDomain", referenced from:
      -[PFImageView loadInBackground:progressBlock:] in ParseUI(PFImageView.o)
      ___46-[PFImageView loadInBackground:progressBlock:]_block_invoke32 in ParseUI(PFImageView.o)
  "_kPFErrorCacheMiss", referenced from:
      ___48-[PFQueryTableViewController loadObjects:clear:]_block_invoke in ParseUI(PFQueryTableViewController.o)
  "_kPFErrorInvalidImageData", referenced from:
      ___46-[PFImageView loadInBackground:progressBlock:]_block_invoke32 in ParseUI(PFImageView.o)
  "_kPFErrorUnsavedFile", referenced from:
      -[PFImageView loadInBackground:progressBlock:] in ParseUI(PFImageView.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

please help me i have to upload my new version release as soon as possible

Comment: Check that you have the right frameworks in the **Linked Frameworks and Libraries** list.
Also check that you have included the right headers from the Parse SDK.

Comment: Try after setting Build Active Architecture Only to YES..

Comment: @bojand i ahve not changed code i just updated frameworks via pods.

Comment: @NileshPatel yes i did it but not working

Comment: @NileshPatel have you tried cleaning your derived data folder?

Comment: In my scenario project is created using Xcode 5 and all my frameworks are drag and drops , when I open the same project in Xcode 7.3 and install frameworks using cocoa pods I got the error what above discuss  
finally found one solution for that create new empty project using Xcode 7.3  install all frameworks in that and carefully drag and drop you project into new project it works nice

Comment: have you opened xcodeproj file in Xcode? instead open workspace file.

Answer (score 4):

Ok, the best way to clean up certain pods related issues is to clean up everything and run again.

I have this standard procedure that works whenever there is a linking error with cocoaPods.

1.Keep a backup!
(This may completely break!)

2.Do a pod deintegrate
Use this library --> https://github.com/CocoaPods/cocoapods-deintegrate to call the `pod deintegrate` command to clean up everything with cocoa pods.

3.Clean up the project settings, by removing everything that was edited. (If you did it for some framework to work, then keep it)
Remove search paths, framework header paths, other linker flags
Remove configs, Remove Flags, Remove PCH if any
Anything that is bold in build settings is edited, whatever is not done explicitly by you for some purpose, delete it to restore back to default value.

4.Delete the workspace, and any pod file from the directory.

4.Paste Back your main pod file from the backup.

5.Delete data from derivedFolder, window-->projects-->delete derived data

6.Do a clean (product --> clean), and even clean build folder (holding option, do product --> clean build folder)

7.Do a pod install

8.Build and run.

Everything should be restored back to happy states!

Answer (score 0):

Just try to set `ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH` to `NO` and back to `YES` on the target (not on project). There's bug in recent Xcode that causes this behaviour. I've spent hours tearing my hair over it.

Answer (score 0):

1.Create New project with currently using Xcode version

2.Install your framework with cocoa pods in new workspace

3.Remove your old project frameworks which you installed using cocoa pods (keep your code backup)

4.Copy your old project code to New project workspace then Build an Run

Answer (score 0):

Did you update the version of the Pod for a reason or was it just a case of you re-running `pod install` and it automatically installed a newer version? If you don't need the newer version, you could try reverting back to 1.6.5. If you want to only ever install a specific version of a Pod, update your Podfile as so:

```
pod 'Parse', '1.6.5'
```

Answer (score 0):

**1** Remove `pod 'Parse'` from your Podfile and run `pod install`

**2** Xcode > View > **Clear All Derived Data**

**3** Add `pod 'Parse' '~> 1.6.5'` to your Podfile and run `pod install`

Answer (score 0):

Try to setup "Other Linker Flags" in Build Settings.
Just add something to this line and remove this and Other linker flags will be regenerated.
[image]